# Save/Reference multiple values in cell of database table

Tags: python, django, database

I am working on a E-commerce website side project. And I need some help in saving data related to Product in Database table.

**Requirement -**

A product can have different sizes available and color available.

Product A - Size - S,M,X,XL and color - Blue, Black, White

Product A - Size - S,M and color - Pink, Red, Orange

Now how can I save Size and color in database for each product.

Could anyone please advice?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I am using Django and in that we have concept of models which are converted to tables. So I am flexible to use mysql, postgresql, or sql server. Which ever fulfills the requirements, I will use that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql you could use the enum type:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

```
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
INSERT INTO shirts (name, size) VALUES ('dress shirt','large'), ('t- shirt'','medium'), ('polo shirt','small');
```

Selecting:

```
SELECT name, size FROM shirts WHERE size = 'medium';
```

Comment: It's a good concept. I will search on how I can implement it through models in django.
Thanks